# Left Margin mismatch in enumerate environment using multline

Tags: enumerate, amsart, multline

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{(\roman*)}]
    \item dajksdhaksdhjaksjdhajksdhaldsghahjsdla
        \begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{\alph*.}]
            \item haskjdaksndasdjkhasdkhausdhiuhawiqkdnjsdnaksdikc          
                \begin{multline*}
    \left( \cos(\pi x) + i\sin(\pi x) + i \right)\left( \cos(\pi x) - i\sin(\pi x) - i \right)\\ = \cos^2(\pi x) - i\sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi x) - i\cos(\pi x) + i\sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi x)\\
     + \sin^2(\pi x) + \sin(\pi x)+ i \cos(\pi x) + \sin(\pi x) + 1 = 2 + 2\sin(\pi x)
                \end{multline*}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}     
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: screenshot]

The problem is, that the beginning of the equation and the indent of the enumerate environment does not match. It just looks ugly. How can I indent the equation in the multline environment (or in a general math environment like equation or gather)?

Comment: I think the best solution is simply redefine `\fullwidthdisplay` by `\renewcommand{\fullwidthdisplay}{}` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220089/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your maths environment in a `minipage` of width the current line width:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{(\roman*)}]
    \item dajksdhaksdhjaksjdhajksdhaldsghahjsdla
        \begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{\alph*.}]
            \item haskjdaksndasdjkhasdkhausdhiuhawiqkdnjsdnaksdikc

            \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
                \begin{multline*}
    \left( \cos(\pi x) + i\sin(\pi x) + i \right)\left( \cos(\pi x) - i\sin(\pi x) - i \right)\\ = \cos^2(\pi x) - i\sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi x) - i\cos(\pi x) + i\sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi x)\\
     + \sin^2(\pi x) + \sin(\pi x)+ i \cos(\pi x) + \sin(\pi x) + 1 = 2 + 2\sin(\pi x)
                \end{multline*}
            \end{minipage}

        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have to do that repeatedly, you can as well define a new `listmultline` environment (unnumbered) as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{listmultline}{\par\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}\start@multline\st@rredtrue}%
{\endmultline\endminipage}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Oh, that is a very good idea. Thanks! If I use this over and over, what is the best way to apply this?

Comment: Maybe define a new environment – here `listmultline`, say. However, be aware it won't break across pages. I've added a way to define such an environment to my answer.