# Using align inside a list

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, enumerate, itemize, amsart

I want to use the align environment inside a list but the equation shouldn't be centered with respect to the pagewidth but with respect to the intented block of the list.

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Some text..
\begin{itemize}
    \item Very import point:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Yet another very important point substantiated by a long equation
        \begin{align*}
            x^2+y^2+5\int_{10003}^{10033455}\sin x\;dx+\tan^2(74638263x^2)=1.
        \end{align*} 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I want to have the long equation centered under point (1).

Comment: By editorial choice, displays in `amsart` are always centered with respect to the text width. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220089/4427

Comment: Is there any way to bypass this behavior?

Comment: Did you look at the linked question?

Comment: Sure, but for their solution I would need to know the actual intend set by amsart.

Comment: Doesn't `\renewcommand{\fullwidthdisplay}{}` suffice?

Answer (score 0):

You simply can nest an `aligned` environment in a `\makebox{\linewidth}` (*not* `\textwidth`). Of course it's up to you to add the vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Some text.
\begin{itemize}

    \item Very import point:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Yet another very important point substantiated by a long equation. \bigskip

      \makebox[\linewidth]{\small$ \begin{aligned}
            & x^2+y^2+5\int_{10003}^{10033455}\sin x\;dx+\tan^2(74638263x^2)=1.\\
            & x^2 + y^2 = z^2.
        \end{aligned} $}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]