# amsart and eqlist equation alignment

Tags: amsmath, lists, article, amsart

When using the class amsart, math is all centered on the page, even if the math is within an eqlist environment, which changes the text width.  Is there a way to get amsart to respect changes in the text width, like with eqlist, when centering equations?

Here is an MWE:

In the usual article class, the integrals here are aligned to the center with respect to the current text width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqlist}

\begin{document}

Here is some math
\[\int\]
\begin{eqlist}
  \item[EQLIST ITEM] Here is some text and math
  \[\int\]
  Here is more text.
\end{eqlist}

\end{document}
```

However, when compiled with `\documentclass{amsart}` instead, the integrals are both centered with respect to the page.

So the question is whether, using the amsart class, the alignment of equations can be made to be as in the article class.

EDIT

This was [solved in another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220089/equation-left-margin) with `\renewcommand{\fullwidthdisplay}{}`.